# Command Manager Create Fact Script not seeing table

Tags: microstrategy

I keep getting a message when I try to run the script below in command manager, that the table isn't in the folder.  However when I look in the folder the table is right there, with "logical table" in the details column.  Can anyone see what the issue is with my script?

```
Code:

CREATE FACT "TestFact" IN FOLDER "\Schema Objects\Facts\BulkFactTest" EXPRESSION "StuffCount" EXPSOURCETABLES "\SCHEMA OBJECTS\TABLES\TableName" FOR PROJECT "ProjectName";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked and it seems you have to omit the base path to the table. Check the outline-example for "Create Fact" of the CommandManager (always helpful).

So this will work:

```
CREATE FACT "TestFact" IN FOLDER "\Schema Objects\Facts\BulkFactTest" EXPRESSION "StuffCount" EXPSOURCETABLES "TableName" FOR PROJECT "ProjectName";
```

Note: even when moving tables/table-aliases to subfolders you have to only provide the table-name in EXPSOURCETABLES. Sadly documentation is not the strong suit of MSTR.

Comment: Guess this also answers your other post as well (https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912144/3203970)